# how to have a listActivity as a tab fragment of actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an Listactivity and i want it as a fragment when someone selects it's tab, 
below is the activity...

```
public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

when i extend sherlockListActivity i get an error on "new SimpleAdapter" saying

```
The constructor SimpleAdapter(PlayListActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined
```

how should i make it a fragment and have it output a list.

Comment: `Fragment`s don't extend `SherLockListActivity`. They extend `Fragment` (in the support library). Review your Android basics at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: android.app.v4.Fragment to be exact :) - lol ur named Phil too xD - and I just thought like jesus when did I write that^^